# trigger office configuration window

Tags: outlook, ms-office

After installed office 2010 apps MUI patches(Word MUI patch, Excel MUI Patch, and so on), Outlook cannot be used with an error message shown as below:

```
------------------------------------
Setup Error
------------------------------------
The setup controller has encountered a problem during install.  Please review the log files for further information on the error.
------------------------------------
OK   
------------------------------------
```

Here I found a way to solve the problem, which is by launching the Word manually, before the Word is ready for use, a configuration window will be triggered. After configuration is successfully done, the Outlook will return to work well. I found the configuration window is from "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft shared\OFFICE14\Office Setup Controller\Setup.exe"

My problem is: how to trigger the configuration window in any script(c#, vbs) by avoiding launching the Word manually, or is there a substitute way for this?
it's a critical issue for me, so any input is greatly appreciated!